# 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed' in Razor's Html.Raw()

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to convert my model into a JSON string, as I wish to use a Knockout binding in this particular view.

First of all, I try to convert the model into a JSON string, like so:

```
@{
    var serializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializerObject(Model, serializerSettings));
}
```

In the last line (the actual conversion), the following error occurs:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

My controller simply gets the object from the DB, just like this:

```
public ActionResult Partner(int id)
{
    using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var partner = db.Partners
            .Include(x => x.OperatingCountries)
            .Include(x => x.Secrets)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id);

        return View(partner);
    }
}
```

I've done exactly the same in another view where this error doesn't occur. What's causing this, and how do I proceed?

Comment: Does `Partner` contain any properties which are collections or complex objects?

Comment: Yes it does. Two of them to be exact; `public virtual ICollection<Country>` and `public virtual ICollection<Secret>`

Comment: You will probably need to use `.Include()` in your query to load them.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, but I already have the includes. Have edited

Answer (score 0):

Entity objects from Entity Framework should not be used for serialization. The same problem happens when you store these objects in the distributed cache.

If you still want to use Entity objects for serialization, disable lazy loading.

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: So basically just make a model containing the same data as the EF object?

Comment: Creating separate model will work. Avoiding lazy loading will also work. Before the query, disable lazy loading. If lazy loading is disabled, there is no need of includes, unless that data is required in views.